# javascript find and replace a dynamic pattern in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have a dynamic pattern that I have been using the code below to find

```
var matcher = new RegExp("%" + dynamicnumber + ":", "g");
var found = matcher.test(textinput);
```

I need the pattern to have a new requirement, which is to include an additional trailing 5 characters of either y or n.  And then delete it or replace it with a '' (nothing).

I tried this syntax for the pattern, but obviously it does not work.

```
var matcher = new RegExp("%" + dynamicnumber + ":"  + /([yn]{5})/, "g");
```

Any tip is appreciated

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only pass the regex string into the RegExp c'tor :

```
var re = new RegExp("%" + number + ":"  + "([yn]{5})", "g");
```

Comment: Thanks Failed, this is exactly what I did last night (or I thought I did), but it did not work. But now I have an alert statement, and it does return the match as 'true', so it does work, but I guess my replace code does not replace.

Comment: I will try to figure it out first since I now have confirmation that the pattern does work.  It is probably something really simple that I missed due to trying to write codes at 2-3am.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
var matcher = new RegExp("(%" + number + ":)([yn]{5})", "g");
```

Then replace it with the contents of the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks Amber, I had something similar to yours, and I guess it did work, I just have something else that did not work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes instead of slashes:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("%" + number + ":([yn]{5})", "g");
```

Also, make sure that `dynamicnumber` or `number` are **valid** RegExps. special characters have to be prefixed by a double slash, `\\`, a literal double slash has to be written as four slashes: `\\\\`.

Comment: Thanks Rob W, I did something similar to this last night, it turns out that it did work, I just have something else that does not work.

Comment: Regular expressions are converted to strings when they're concanated with a string: `"%" + /[yn]{5}/` > `"%/[yn]{5}/"`.

Comment: @Jamex In your first RegExp, you were using `dynamicnumber`. In the second RegExp, however, you're using `number`. Are you sure that this is correct?

Comment: @Rob W, I just forgot to change the text when I posted, but your suggestion does work.  I just need to figure out why I can't replace the pattern in my string, probably something simple. Thanks.